# Consuming RESTful web services

Tags: 8, services

Is there any existing Drupal 8 module (on drupal.org, GitHub or anywhere else) that would leverage Guzzle to consume JSON and/or HAL+JSON Web Services over REST?

Alternatively, is the recommended way to necessarily write a custom module leveraging the Guzzle HTTP Client that ships with Drupal core?

My end goal is to be able to create a 1:1 relationship to map fields (node, user...) with key/value pairs from RESTful web services. Then I need to be able to read, update or delete those values.

Comment: I think you're missing one of the important points behind Drupal 8 here - if a piece of functionality already exists in a well-established library, it's not going to be reproduced for Drupal 8. "Proudly Invented Elsewhere" is the mantra now, instead of the old "Not Invented Here" mentality. So yeah, use Guzzle :) Or pick another PHP-based REST client (like [HTTPFul](http://phphttpclient.com/)). But I wouldn't expect that sort of thing to wind up in a module, unless it's just to wrap their functionality in a symfony service to help with DI, but you may as well do that yourself

Comment: Well yes, I don't want to reinvent the wheel either. Thus why one option I'm thinking about would be to take what's in core (Guzzle), and have a GUI Drupal module built on top of it to be able to map Drupal fields with JSON data that you could pull on demand.

Comment: Oh I see - sorry, I glossed over the last paragraph somehow. Sounds like the sort of functionality the core aggregator module gives you, maybe that can be leveraged in some way? A custom fetcher/parser/processor combination might be the way to go

Comment: Looks like this would have to be custom, because I don't know of any way in Drupal 8 to (yet) leverage the core Aggregator module to do anything else but retrieve XML-based formats. In my wonderland, I would also not wait on cron runs to handle things. I'd have to most likely rely on Rules to trigger events on viewing/saving nodes/user accounts and, if needed, PUT/PATCH the resource object.

Comment: Yeah looking at the code a bit more it would probably be more work to extend that than to just write it from scratch. I guess another challenge with that sort of setup is having to maintain identical entity/field config between the two different sites (unless you're consuming the same install from the client of course). If you start writing anything as a public module let me know I'd be happy to contribute

Comment: I absolutely will and thanks for offering to contribute!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OH, just realized now, maybe I misunderstood the question 100%

This is the code which basically generates the output:

```
$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer'):
$output = $serializer->serialize($entity, $format);
```

with $format for example being 'json'.

Luckily the serializer is symetric, so you can do the same the other way round.

```
$client = \Drupal::service('http_client');
$result = $client->get('http://example.com/entity/node/1', ['Accept' => 'application/json']);
$output = $result->getBody();

$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer'):
$entity = $serializer->deserialize($output, 'Drupal\node\Entity\Node', $format);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a good starting point for what I want to achieve.

Comment: What happens when the `$output` is an array of an unknown content type?

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTTP Client Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client_manager) module page:

> Http Client Manager introduces a new Guzzle based plugin which allows
>   you to manage HTTP clients using Guzzle Service Descriptions via JSON
>   files, in a simple and efficient way

Answer (score 0):

There is a module "RESTful Web Services" - Exposes entities and other resources as RESTful web API. The guzzle is the standard http **client** used in the Drupal core. "RESTful Web Services" It is modified module "Services" from Drupal 7. It is the **service**. But the idea is the same. To communicate any service with Drupal as a service.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mTTfCZ8Iac

Comment: If you're talking about https://www.drupal.org/project/restws I know it's been added to Drupal 8 to expose entities and I'm familiar with how to expose those entites already. My question is rather to determine the best way (ideally via an existing module) to _consume_ those exposed entities on another Drupal 8 site.

Comment: I understand you need a Drupal client to Drupal services. Drupal is alpha now. So There are not such modules for Drupal 8. You can study such modules: Migrate(It is the main D8 migration module). You can create a source that communicates with services. You can also look at the module Feeds and the module feeds_import https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import. The module feeds exists for D8. You can help to migrate this module.

Comment: D8 to D8 migrations won't likely make it before 8.1.x so I don't count on it too much for now. I think "_no such module exists for Drupal 8_" is a fine answer and what I understand is it'd be preferable to build custom code to achieve the expected behavior.